# 'at whim' vs 'on a whim'

Tags: difference

What are the similarities and differences? Are there any general lessons or implications?

[Wordreference.com (banned) user 'Ume'](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=410209&p=5376214#post5376214) claims:

> I've found "at whim", not "at a whim", in both the *LONGMAN Dictionary of Contemporary English* and the *Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary*. What difference is there between "at whim" and "on a whim". Neither of the dictionaries don't say that.

[Wordreference.com Senior Member 'Loob'](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=410209&p=5376214#post5376214) states without proof:

> I'd say the difference between "on a whim" and "at whim" is that "on a whim" relates to a single event, "at whim" to repeated occurrences.

Comment: Few usage dictionary I checked, and unfortunately they don't include the word ***whim***. In dictionaries, though, it does have mention of *at whim, on whim, on the whim of**, but they don't say if they have any difference in meaning, or if at all they have any. The only link I have managed to find which says about the the slight difference between ***on a whim*** and ***at whim*** is the link you provided. It seems true because in the example sentences **at whim** is associated with repeated occurrences. http://tinyurl.com/mfb788v

Answer (score 4):

*On a whim* is used far more often than *at whim*.  One hears "on a whim" ten times a week whereas one reads "at whim" and then only rarely.

The phrase "at whim" means "for no apparent reason, randomly, arbitrarily, whenever the impulse arises, or whenever one likes"

**The paramilitaries were walking through the village, torching huts at whim.**

**I cannot kick back and read a good book at whim these days; there's far too much work to be done to the house.**

The phrase "on *a* whim" refers to a particular instance of unplanned, impromptu behavior:

**On a whim, I gave her a call and asked her out.

We went to the beach on a whim.**

Answer (score 3):

I can't make sense of what user "Ume" is saying, but the Member "Loob" seems to have nailed it.

"on a whim" refers to a single event.

e.g.: He went deep sea fishing, on a whim.

"at whim" is more general, and usually implies multiple occurrences.

e.g.: He was shooting three pointers at whim.